# Laravel 4 - when calling instance which is not defined - script stops but does not show errors

Tags: php, laravel

Made simple controller:

```
class TestController extends BaseController {

public function postTurnover() {
    // error_reporting(-1); does not add more 
    echo 'post';

    $formData = array('a');

    //$utils = new Utilities\Utils;  // if this is commented, script stops executing 
    // when calling  $utils object, but not showing any errors
    $formData['shops'] = $utils->franchisesShopsDropdown(1, 1); 



    die('aaa'); // not going even till there when calling non existing object



}
}
```

Can someone explain why no errors? Only displays word 'post'

Instalation is default, in the config/app.php there is 'debug' => true,

Comment: have you checked your error_log?

Comment: no, but ok already as Y U NO WORK answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
 ini_set("display_errors", true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```